# Getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

Maven is not able to identify `testng.xml` file. Getting exception as follows:

> Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException:
>   Suite file
>   D:\selenium-workspace\web-automation\src\main\resources\RegressionSuite.xml
>   is not a valid file

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>web-automation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>mycompany.web.automation project</name>
  <description>mycompany.web.automation project</description>

  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.10</version>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <properties>
       <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/RegressionSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
       <skipTests>false</skipTests>
 </properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
          <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.12.4</version>
                 <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                   <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                 </configuration>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

**Regression.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
  <test name="Test">
      <parameter name="username" value="user@example.com"></parameter>
      <parameter name="password" value="password123"></parameter>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.test1.test.TestClassOne"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**output**

> T E S T S
>
> ---
>
> org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
>       Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file
>   D:\selenium-workspace\web-automation\src\main\resources\RegressionSuite.xml
>   is not a valid file
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:124)
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:89)
>     ... 9 more
>
> Results :
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: Could you provide some more information, such as the code that's causing the error? We can't really do a whole lot with what you give us now.. [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i have added some error reports and pom.xml,testng.xml. Is that enough?please let me know

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about the naming of the xml file? In the pasted snippet you named the file Regression.xml.